Why is my MicroSD Card Reader not being recognized?
Important Edit:
I have switched to using a mini USB SSD (the Samsung Fit 256 GB) to store my data, instead of a MicroSD card. Because of this, I will not be monitoring this post for answers.
Summary
I have recently set up a dual-boot system on my HP ProBook G40 G5, running Windows 11 and Fedora 40, which has been great.
However, the main problem I'm having is that my 256 GB Samsung MicroSD card (originally formatted with exFAT, then re-formatted to NTFS) isn't being recognized by Fedora, but it is by Windows.
By “isn't being recognized”, I mean that the drive itself (not the partitions) can't be detected by Fedora. I can't modify or even view the partitions using GParted. The device doesn't even show up as an option.

Diagnostics
If I run fdisk -l without sudo:
fdisk: cannot open /dev/nvme0n1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/mmcblk0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/zram0: Permission denied

It shows the MicroSD (mmcblk), but then when I run it
with sudo:
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: KXG50ZNV256G TOSHIBA                    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 17E72FEB-9F5E-4577-A3F3-DDD7B8C2EB79

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    739327    737280  360M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    739328   1001471    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1001472 319666175 318664704  152G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 458756096 460763135   2007040  980M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 460763136 500107263  39344128 18.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6 319666176 321763327   2097152    1G Linux extended boot
/dev/nvme0n1p7 321763328 458756095 136992768 65.3G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/zram0: 7.59 GiB, 8154775552 bytes, 1990912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

It only shows two of my drives, the swap (zram), and the actual internal SSD (nvme0n); it doesn't show the MicroSD (mmcblk).
Another thing: when I remove and then re-insert the MicroSD, then drive being connected sound plays.
dmesg output (that looks related):
[ 1332.518784] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1332.692745] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1332.694402] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1332.865897] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[ 1332.867972] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read

I have no idea what this means or where to start.
lsmod | head -10 output:
Module                  Size  Used by
uinput                 20480  0
rfcomm                102400  4
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12288  1
nf_conntrack_broadcast    12288  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nft_fib_inet           12288  1
nft_fib_ipv4           12288  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_fib_ipv6           12288  1 nft_fib_inet

Trying to load kernel module rts5139:
modprobe: FATAL: Module rts5139 not found in directory /lib/modules/6.10.12-200.fc40.x86_64

People say you need to update your kernel, but I'm already on the newest installation of Fedora.

Other Details
The drive was originally exFAT, but thinking it was an exFAT issue, I reformatted the MicroSD on Windows to NTFS, which I know Linux could read.
These are the packages related to MicroSD that I have installed (that I know of):

opensc.x86_64


My theory on this is that the problem is a missing/misconfigured driver, but I not sure.
I just know that it's not an exFAT issue, and not a broken card issue, as Windows 11 can still read it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Updates
Found from the sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell command:
Oct 07 12:49:35 fedora gnome-shell[2203]: Unable to mount volume Data: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /run/media/{[(MY USER NAME)]}/Data: can't read superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1

Seems like there's something completely wrong with the way the internal data of the MicroSD is laid out, and Fedora can't read it.
More dmesg errors/infomation:
[  234.042634] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[  234.221533] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  234.223144] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  234.913371] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  235.003745] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 500695039 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  235.550698] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  235.680958] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  293.939673] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  294.114097] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  294.116145] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  294.117530] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  294.118184] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  294.118577] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  294.205414] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
[  294.713692] I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[  294.713787] FAT-fs (mmcblk0): unable to read boot sector


Was the "disk" in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

@waltinator Yes, the drive was used with Windows when fast-startup (or fast boot) was turned on. However, to dual-boot Windows 11 and Linux, it's required to turn off fast-startup anyway, and I haven't run any Windows updates since then. So no, fast-startup isn't currently enabled on my Windows 11, and so the last time I used Windows, it shouldn't have been on, changing the disk.
